# Incompatible types when passing a struct

Tags: c, struct, monitor

I have a program that creates multiple threads for a monitor(abstract object that only runs one thread at a time) test in C.  I was getting errors where it seemed to work but obviously failed elsewhere, I think due to each thread getting its own monitor.

**I need to somehow pass the struct or a pointer to it from one program to the other** so that I can make sure they all point to the same one.  In this implementation I get a segmentation fault and I think much more work without guidance will just make the program more convoluted.

There must be a better way to define this Struct than simply having its definition in both programs?

Relevant Monitor code:

```
#define N 5
#include<stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>

struct cond {
   int blocked;
   sem_t sema,empty, full;
   int count;
    char buf[N];
};

void waitNotEmpty(struct cond mon);
void waitNotFull(struct cond mon);
//void signalNotEmpty(void);
//void signalNotFull(void);
struct cond spawnMonitor(void);
void moninsert(char alpha, struct cond mon);
char monremove(struct cond mon);

struct cond spawnMonitor(void){
    struct cond mon;
    sem_init(&mon.sema, 0, 1);
    mon.blocked = 0;
    sem_init(&mon.empty, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&mon.full, 0, 1);
    mon.count = 0;
    int value; 
    sem_getvalue(&mon.sema, &value); 
     printf("INITIAL VALUE: %d\n", value);
     return mon;
}
```

and the MonitorDemo program that runs it:

```
#define N 10000000
#include<stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>


struct cond {
    int blocked;
    sem_t sema,empty, full;
    int count;
    char buf[N];
};

struct cond mon;

void main (void)
{

    void producer ();
    void consumer ();

    int i = 0;
    pthread_t thread[10];
    mon = spawnMonitor();
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, (void *) producer, NULL);
        i++;
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, (void *) consumer, NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a better way to define the struct than having it in both programs; you can put it in a header file that gets included from both programs.  But that won't solve a `Incompatible types when passing a struct` error.  If you are getting that error, please post an SSCCE that demonstrates the error and point out exactly which line the error happens on.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: Note that you have incompatible types because N is 5 in one file and 10,000,000 in the other!  `void main()` is invalid on systems where you use `pthread.h` (unless you're using POSIX threads on Windows, which seems improbable).  You should be defining the `struct` (all aspects of it, including the value of `N`) in a header file.

Comment: Unrelated: Your `main()` is in a world of hurt as it is. As soon as those threads are all launched and the for-loop finishes there is nothing stopping `main()` from terminating. You never join even one of threads you spawn. I suggest while revisiting the books on your structure compatibility, said same is done for your pthread text.

Comment: I correct the N =5 or 100000 problem and added a header file.  The threads need not join (I assume this means come together with whatever data is collected) as it is only to test them interacting with the array, I switched the while loop to a for (i:1 to 5) to simplify though.  Should I delay the main thread from ending then?  Some kind of while (threads != done) loop perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I delay the main thread from ending then? Some kind of while
>   (threads != done) loop perhaps?

[POSIX Threads Programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#CreatingThreads) says about **Terminating Threads**:

- There is a definite problem if main() finishes before the threads it spawned if you don't call `pthread_exit()` explicitly. All of the threads it created will terminate because main() is done and no longer exists to support the threads.
- By having main() explicitly call `pthread_exit()` as the last thing it does, main() will block and be kept alive to support the threads it created until they are done.